# Clarifications on Botium support

Tags: testing, chatbot

I'm evaluating Botium for chatbot testing. Could you please confirm if Botium supports below operations ?

1. UI testing - Send request from ChatBot UI and capture the response from UI (Black box testing)
2. How Botium handles dynamic requests and dynamic responses  (Not static content requests/responses in the excel sheet). Dynamic requests/responses are prepared from difference sources like database, APIs etc.,

Please let me know if more details are needed in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** Yes. Botium includes a Webdriver connector based on Selenium, so you can drive your test cases against the web user interface of your chatbot. More info [in the repository](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-webdriverio). A simple example for a botium.json doing UI tests:

```
{
  "botium": {
    "Capabilities": {
      "PROJECTNAME": "WebdriverIO Plugin Sample",
      "CONTAINERMODE": "webdriverio",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_OPTIONS": {  
        "desiredCapabilities": {
          "browserName": "chrome"      
        }
      },
      "WEBDRIVERIO_URL": "secret",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_INPUT_ELEMENT": "#textInput",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_INPUT_ELEMENT_SENDBUTTON": ".btn-weiter",
      "WEBDRIVERIO_OUTPUT_ELEMENT": ".from-watson"
    }
  }
}
```

**Question 2:** Botium supports severall "matching modes" to assert if you consider the test case as success or not. Substring matching is the most simple one, then there are regular expression, synonym lists, and you can even plug in your own assertion logic ... furthermore, there is something called a "scripting memory" which makes it possible to re-use dynamic content later in the conversation. Some examples are available in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@floriantreml/botium-in-a-nutshell-part-2-writing-chatbot-tests-8726204c8da6). A simple example for a convo file using the scripting memory:

```
...

#bot
Super! I've found $count locations for you. Which one would you like to drive to?

#me
$count

#bot
Sure! Restaurant $count on the list gets great reviews.

...
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Florian. Your quick response is appreciated. Will contact you if more details are needed in this regard.